# taking id from a specific table and altering it

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how can i take last used index from a specific table and add a +1 to it?

```
database login, table cars
```

I think i need to add it here ####

```
protected function handle_file_upload($uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error,
            $index = null, $content_range = null) {
        $file = parent::handle_file_upload(
            $uploaded_file, $name, $size, $type, $error, $index, $content_range
        );
        if (empty($file->error)) {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$this->options['db_table']
                .'` (`carID`,`name`, `size`, `type`, `title`, `description`)'
                .' VALUES (#############,?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
            $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $query->bind_param(
                'sisss',
                $file->name,
                $file->size,
                $file->type,
                $file->title,
                $file->description
            );
            $query->execute();
            $file->id = $this->db->insert_id;
        }
        return $file;
    }
```

EDITED:
I should have went more detail on the question. Im doing a car dealership website. There's this big form of car info and there's an ajax image upload.  So i need to tie the images with the rest of the info about the car. My car info form has an auto increment id row in the database. So i'm trying to tie the images to the car by the cars id (i want every uploaded image to have the car id). I have this mysql insert code and i want to add the value of the last updated table id (from the car table) and add +1 to it. Is it a good idea? or should i go another way?

Comment: Why not just use an `auto_increment` column and let the database do this automatically for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `carID` is an auto-increment value then you don't have to do anything. The DB will do this for you. Just leave the value empty (`null`) like this

```
INSERT INTO `'.$this->options['db_table']
            .'` (`carID`,`name`, `size`, `type`, `title`, `description`)'
            .' VALUES (null,?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Or remove the column from your insert statement

```
INSERT INTO `'.$this->options['db_table']
            .'` (,`name`, `size`, `type`, `title`, `description`)'
            .' VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make **carID** column `AUTOINCREMENT` . No need then to insert carID values .

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$this->options['db_table']
                .'` (`name`, `size`, `type`, `title`, `description`)'
                .' VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
```

[**See here.**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)